# Format floating point number with leading zeros

Tags: java, string-formatting

Why does

```
System.out.format("%03.3f", 1.23456789);
```

print `1.235` instead of `001.235`?

How has my `format` string to look like to get `001.235` as output of the following code line?

```
System.out.format(format, 1.23456789);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Number after `%0` here defines full width including decimal point, so you need to change it to `7`:

```
System.out.format("%07.3f", 1.23456789);
```

Comment: I would suggest formatting the string first and then outputting it. `String.format("%07.3f", 1.23456789);`

Comment: @DanielTung In case I don't need the string for anything else why would I first format and then output it?

Answer (score 4):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
formatter.applyPattern("000.###");
System.out.format(formatter.format(1.23456789));
```

Result:

001.234

[Demo](http://ideone.com/G7zwQt)